# Using curly brackets (braces) to create folder structure with `mkdir -p`

Tags: shell, brace-expansion

As `man mkdir` states

```
   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

When I ran this command

```
mkdir -p work/{F1,F2,F3}/{temp1,temp2}
```

It creates a folder structure like this `work` parent folder then `F1`,`F2`,`F3` child folders 
and `temp1` and `temp2` child folders under three parent folder `F1`,`F2`,`F3`.

```
   work
     -F1
       -temp1
       -temp2
     -F2
       -temp1
       -temp2
     -F3
       -temp1
       -temp2
```

Now the problem is that I want to create `temp1`,`temp2` folders only under `F1` not under `F2` and `F3`, but I'm confused on how I can write a command to do what I want.

Comment: @Caleb: sorry, I was not aware we were both editing at the same time, it seems that revision merging is not implemented by SE :-/

Comment: @Stephane: No worries. I've made a lot of edits and it's pretty rare that two major edits get clobbered like that. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for?

```
 mkdir -p work/{F1/{temp1,temp2},F2,F3}
```

Comment: Hey, I was wondering recently if things could be done as simple as that. Thanks!

Comment: how about adding variables inside the curly braces? Like so : `mkdir -p work/{F1/{"$var"},F2,F3}`, where `var='temp1,temp2'`.

Answer (score 3):

A very good description of brace expansion (with examples) can be found at subsection `Brace Expansion` of bash manual (`man bash`, press `/` to start search and search for `Brace Expansion`).

Comment: Thank you, your answer led me to this great guide! Just needed to know that it's called "Brace Expansion" so I knew what to google. http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0080.php Excerpt: 
"Perhaps the strangest expansion is called brace expansion. With it, you can create multiple text strings from a pattern containing braces. Here's an example:

`[me@linuxbox me]$ echo Front-{A,B,C}-Back`
`Front-A-Back Front-B-Back Front-C-Back`"

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p work/F{1..3} work/F1/temp{1,2}
```

This first creates `work` and the three subdirectories before creating the lower level directories of `work/F1`.  It's easy to read and to understand.

Or, if you absolutely need to combine everything into a single monster expression (there is absolutely no need to do so as it's difficult to read and maintain):

```
mkdir -p work/F{1/temp{1,2},2,3}
```

Comment: how about adding variables inside the curly braces? Like so : `mkdir -p work/{F1/{"$var"},F2,F3}`, where `var='temp1,temp2'`

Comment: @Snow Did you try that to see what happens?

Comment: yes, it creates a single folder named "{temp1,temp2}"

Comment: @Snow Yes, the order of evaluation is such that the brace expansion happens first and the expansion of variables later.  This means that the value of a variable can not affect a brace expansion.